# Access control on Firebase databases

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, access-control

We are having different environments for one of our solution (`test, preprod, prod`). We've created different Firebase databases as part of single project on Firebase console. We want to have access control implemented to these databases depending on users or groups e.g. **prod** Firebase database will be accessible to only few users where as other environment's (`test and preprod`) Firebase database will be accessible to most of the users.

Are we implementing it correctly? If yes, would it be possible to configure Firebase project to have this kind of setup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the recommended way to implement different development environments.  The only recommended way to separate environments is to create different Firebase projects for each one.  This ensures that they each have completely isolated data, users, security rules, and so on.  Adding multiple databases to the same project isn't true isolation, and could lead to problems later on.

Comment: Thanks for giving the right direction. I would really appreciate if you could provide some links or blogs that I can refer to for this implementation.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments